# Buffer overrun; VS Code analysis

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

When enabling static code analysis in VS 2012, the following code fails with a buffer over run.

```
    SimulationData result = rri->getSimulationResult();

    //Extract the data and return struct..
    RRResult* aResult  = new RRResult;

    aResult->RSize = result.rSize();
    aResult->CSize = result.cSize();
    int size = aResult->RSize*aResult->CSize;
    aResult->Data = new double[size];

    int index = 0;
    //The data layout is simple row after row, in one single long row...
    for(int row = 0; row < aResult->RSize; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < aResult->CSize; col++)
        {
            aResult->Data[index++] = result(row, col); //Over run here! but how?
        }
    }
```

The RRResult is a structure and Data is a double pointer. The SimulationData is a class with 'hidden' data with size rSize *cSize. 
I can't see how this code can fail.

Can anyone spot any problem with it?

Comment: Might help to see the implementation of SimulationData::operator() (a.k.a., result()).

Comment: It would help even *more* to see the actual description from the results of the static code analysis.

Comment: What are the types of `aResult->RSize` and `aResult->CSize`? It looks like overflow in the multiplication.

Comment: The types of RSize and CSize are ints.

Comment: here is description from the code analysis window (edited to fit):
C6386 Write overrun Buffer overrun while writing to 'aResult->Data':  the writable size is 'size*8' bytes, but '24' bytes might be written. 
'index' may equal 2 
Invalid write to 'aResult->Data[2]', (writable range is 0 to 0)

Comment: The write over run is in te aResult->Data[index++] assignment, but I can't see how that can ever happen, looking at the over all logic here.

Comment: You could still have overflow in the multiplication, but then you'd have an awful lot of data. What are the values of `RSize` and `CSize` when the code analysis complains?

Comment: Don't know how the static test is done and what RSize and CSize is for the test. The test info says 'index' may equal 2. Invalid write to aResult->Data[2], writable range is 0 to 0